# Sort CSV data in ascending order by the column number

Tags: ruby, csv

I want to sort CSV data like this:

```
"key1","1007829"
"key2","1003196"
"key3","999604"
```

by the ascending order of the number of the second column, like shown below. So I want a CSV result like like:

```
"key3","999604"
"key2","1003196"
"key1","1007829"
```

What can I do?

Comment: What is "column number"?

Comment: how large is your CSV file? e.g. how many lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lines = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv")
sorted_lines = lines.sort_by{|line| line[1].to_i}
```

This will read in the entire csv as an array of `line_arrays`.

It will sort the `line_arrays` by the second value, converted to integer.

Comment: wrong syntax, opening with `(` but closing with `}`

Comment: @RAJ I don't see it, where's that happening?

Comment: It was corrected now, i saw sort_of followed by( it's like soft_by(

Comment: Is there anyway to do this that doesn't read the whole into memory?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter you could use `CSV.for_each("path/to/file.csv")` with a block to read the CSV one line at a time.  You can then output the data to a new file (use a space separator and remove the quotes around the numeric column).  You can then sort the file in place using the linux command `$ sort -k 2n new_file.txt > sorted_file.txt` and finally read in the sorted file.

Alterntively you could write each file to a database table and read it back with an order clause on the second column.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Great suggestions, thanks! I'm thinking a linux command line would be the most optimal route using `system` or something, and then read the sorted file into Ruby. Cheers.